# Toggle class on clicking check box

Tags: ember.js

I'm following the [official Ember guide](http://emberjs.com/guides).

On the step [Displaying a Model's Complete State](http://emberjs.com/guides/getting-started/displaying-a-models-completeness/), the following code is supposed to toggle the class `completed`:

```
  <ul id="todo-list">
    {{#each}}
    <li {{bind-attr class="isCompleted:completed"}}>
      <input type="checkbox" class="toggle">
      <label>{{title}}</label><button class="destroy"></button>
    </li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
```

But nothing seems to happen. Is it something obvioius in the code that is wrong or otherwise debug - how do I debug this?

Comment: Where are you access to isCompleted property?

Comment: I'm not very experienced with the framework, but I assume you mean the Model? I've followed the Guide so the Model is defined according to the following: http://emberjs.com/guides/getting-started/using-fixtures/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use an `{{input}}` helper. For example:

```
{{input type="checkbox" name="isCompleted" checked=isCompleted}}
```

In that case, `isCompleted` is bound to the current model property or a computed property (which could originate from a controller, the model, etc.).

See this guide for more info: http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/input-helpers/#toc_checkboxes

Comment: It's funny how they're using one technique in the example app and then another in the docs :s

Comment: Ah, indeed. They definitely have some work to do in terms of coagulating documentation with the examples and cookbook recipes. Ember does require the dev to get a feel for certain patterns. Had the same learning curve as Rails in some ways, at least for me. :) Overall, though, I am happy with the docs.